# can test-only command in Play Framework accept parameters e.g. file path

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I use Play Framework 2.0 in the project

I need to pass an argument to my test case **com.abc.project.filetest**(filetest is a test class) e.g. file path "/var/tmp/1.txt"

But i dont know how to pass this argument to this test method.Can i run this test case with something like **test-only com.abc.project.filetest /var/tmp/1.txt** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible and I would not recommend this.

What you could do instead is create a directory, say `resources`, under the `test` directory where you have your external files that you want to use in your tests. Then from your tests point to your files relatively, like `String fileName ="test/resources/1.txt";`.